# Calculating the average of 2 columns and writing the result in an existing column

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table in an Access Database in which I have 2 columns filled with values.

In this same table I have a third column in which I would like to have the average of these two columns.

[image: Demping]

What is the best way for me to do this?

I need to save the average in "ReeleDemping" because I need that value later on in a report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best not to calculate and store the averages unless you have a very specific reason to do so.  The proper form way to approach this is to have a query where you calculate the average

```
SELECT GemetenDe1, GemetenDe2, (GemetenDe1+GemetenDe2)/2 AS GementenDeAvg
FROM MyTableName
```

Comment: The reason I want to store the Average is because I need to show value 1, value 2 AND the average value on a report in the end.

Comment: You can do that with a query as well, just have all the fields you want to show on your report in your `SELECT`.  Then change the `RecordSource` of your report to the query

Comment: I don't really understand how. I have 3 reports and it would be most convenient for me if all the values I needed are in 1 table

Comment: See where I have GemetenDe1, GemetenDe2 etc.  Just write out all the fields you need in here.  Or you can use the access query builder where it is all point and click (click that button called query design)

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/create2007.php has a pretty good guide if you're unsure on how to start building queries